# Installing Video Drivers

Tags: 14.04

How can I install all video-drivers in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit? I have no idea what videocard I have.

A guide for 64 bit is also welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install all video drivers with the package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

Answer (score 1):

To [find out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card) which video card you have, you can run

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Based on that, you can then search to find out which drivers to install.

Comment: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

That is the output, but I can only find drivers for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Additional Driver" dialog:

[image]

Or from a terminal `software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`

You will get some suggestions for your video card.